# Cant query WMI when in Administrator mode

Tags: c#, windows, wmi, windows-10

I took half a day to realize that all my queries to WMI were returning with a count of 0 whenever the program (c#) was running in administrator mode, however whenever it was run normally it would receive the count of 7 (which is the right count value I should be getting) and its associated values. This problem also happens under debugging mode if VS is running in ADMIN mode.

This is under windows 10 final (and complete updated as of 31-07-2015). Tried different frameworks (4.0->4.6) in case it had anything to do with that, although obviously it did not.

Here is the code that works under normal circumstances, but not under ADMIN mode:

```
public static Dictionary<String, String> GetNetworkDrives()
        {
            Dictionary<String, String> RetuningDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                        "SELECT * FROM Win32_MappedLogicalDisk");
                MessageBox.Show("Query count: " + searcher.Get().Count.ToString());
                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    //Console.WriteLine("Win32_MappedLogicalDisk instance");
                    //Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    MessageBox.Show(queryObj["VolumeName"] + "||" + queryObj["DeviceID"]);
                    //String stuff = queryObj["ProviderName"] + "||" + queryObj["DeviceID"]; //queryObj["VolumeName"]
                    //Console.WriteLine(stuff);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("No errors");
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Error");
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
            }
            return RetuningDic;
        }
```

Clarification of the code: Return on a messagebox the letter and the folder/volume name of a mapped network location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the remarks of [Win32_MappedLogicalDisk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394194(v=vs.85).aspx), especially:

> However, whether instances are returned depends on the Local Security Policy settings in the Control Panel Administrative Tools. If the following policy is set to "Object Creator", then no mapped drive instances are returned, even if A is a member of the Administrators group:
>   "System object: default owner for objects created by members of the administrators group."

and

> If there is more than one session for user A on the machine, then no mapped drive instances are returned (because the provider has no reasonable way of deciding which session to use).

So there are some situations where Win32_MappedLogicalDisk does not return drives even though they are added. I would probably check for security settings, policies, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that explains everything